# How to describe someone the facial movement of a person start realizing a series problem that they never thought of?

Tags: vocabulary

Trying to find the best way to describe above.
For example:
"frown and sketching head?"

Comment: Is there a single facial expression for this action?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**nod of disbelief/shake one's head in disbelief** might cover this situation.

> **shake** verb. If you shake your head, you turn it from side to side in order to say
> 'no' or to show **disbelief** or **sadness** [Cobuild](https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/en/english-cobuild/to+shake+one%27s+head+in+disbelief)

[Shaking Head in Disbelief](https://tenor.com/search/shaking-head-in-disbelief-gifs) (gifs)

It's often accompanied by a frown.

> You **shake your head in disbelief** at the large fees you have to pay
> for his services. [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shake%20your%20head%20in%20disbelief%22&biw=1066&bih=544&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk036_9uT1NuUQKL0erP8q1kgdu8g8w%3A1629236464376&ei=8CwcYfaTFpbPtQb01avABg&oq=%22shake%20your%20head%20in%20disbelief%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10607.11263.0.11812.5.5.0.0.0.0.136.405.2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.301...33i10k1.0.gVxIJ_aETvE).

> The intricacies don't stop there, however. An option, if you were not
> at fault in your accident, is to make a claim against the other
> driver's liability policy. Go ahead and **shake your head in disbelief**,
> but you might need a separate attorney for... [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Surviving_an_Auto_Accident/Pk1DIoD6HUwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22shake%20your%20head%20in%20disbelief%22).

> With a **nod of disbelief** I was then allowed to continue and went into a
> condensed version of the dissertation that I had received from Ljuba.
> [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dead_Man_s_Odyssey/mWtvoO7BJxMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nod%20of%20disbelief%22&pg=PA86&printsec=frontcover).

> “I was the same distance away from the bomber as Dr. Applebaum.” With
> a **nod of disbelief** he added: “But he was killed with his daughter and
> I wasn't. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Terror/BzouWqFtv0AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nod%20of%20disbelief%22&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestion and examples.

Comment: Realizing something you've never thought of isn't disbelief.

Comment: @gotube I get off the phone and say to you "That was my mother. She's getting remarried! *I can't believe it*!" I say that because I'm realizing it evidently is true. Note the OP said *start realizing,*  the are *coming to grips* with a a realization -- not wanting to believe it. I put gifs there for the OP to check out.

Comment: That would be both disbelief *and* realizing a problem. They are not the same thing. The body language may be similar though

Comment: I believe that it's more a combination: realizing something (including obstacles, problems, etc.) in disbelief. But yes, a nod of disbelief is more general than just a realization of problems.